# Reduce number of results returned by elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using an ngram analyzer for doing auto complete search on a particular field using elasticsearch.
By default I have set the number of results to return to 10 using "size:10" inside the query.

But what I want is that as my search nears the exact match, the results returned by elastic search should reduce

For example
If searching for: `"fl"`
Will return : `"flake", "flower", "fleet", "flank", "flatter"`.

If searching for: `"fla"`
Will return : `"flan","flank", "flatter"`.

If searching for: `"flan"`
Will return : `"flan","flank"`.

Right now all results are returned even if I search for  `"flan"`
I am also using phonetic search.

Comment: Is your data multilingual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is applicable if your data is not multilingual (only if data language is just english)

Use a custom analyzer. You can set the analyzer name to **default** (instead of myAnalyzer), if you want that to be your default analyzer in all cases.

```
index :
analysis :
    analyzer : 
        myAnalyzer :
            type : custom
            tokenizer : whitespace
            filter : [word_filter, lowercase, stop]
    filter :
        word_filter :
            type : word_delimiter
            split_on_numerics : false
            generate_word_parts : false
            generate_number_parts : false
            split_on_case_change : false
            preserve_original : false
```

PS: You need to create the indices and reindex the entire data again after this change.

Answer (score 0):

One way to considerably reduce latency is that rather than using unigram as min_gram, use digrams or trigrams. Otherwise if the user will type just a single letter (for example 'a'), there may be hundreds of thousands of results from the database, which won't be even 'remotely-relevant' for the user (and very inefficient).

You can use this kind of filter:

```
{

 "filter": 
{
            "autocomplete_filter": {
                "type":     "edge_ngram",
                "min_gram": 3,
                "max_gram": 20
            }
    }

}
```

This will significantly reduce the number of results by removing the irrelevant ones, which will improve the efficiency of your software.

You can check out [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html) page for full documentation.

For making even better suggestor, I recommend you to go through [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current//search-suggesters-completion.html) . This will not only limit your results according to given query (just the way you want) but will also considerably improve the efficiency of the software!